# Displaying A PFUser's Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have three views. The first view displays the `PFUsers` in a `PFQueryTableViewController` with the object `client`. The user can press on an the `PFUser` then it will segue showing the detail view with a bunch of information on the `client` object. The I have a button `Points` which I'm trying to show the points that the client has made in that season, this is its own object `points`. I want to show this all in  a `PFQueryTableViewController`. So what Im stuck on is showing that `PFUsers` `Point` object in the last `PFQueryTableViewController`. Here Is how it looks in the storyboard (I know it might sound a tad confusing so I added the image)

[image]

Here is how I retrieve the `client object`:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // Custom the table

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"client";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"name";

        //self.imageKey = @"imageFile";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = NO;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 50;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Segue to the `Detail View`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // "showDetail" is the default segue identifier in a new Master-Detail Project for Table Cell -> Detail View
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"show"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        // Pass the PFObject at this row to the detail view
        PFObject *object = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
```

Trying to Display the `PFUser/Clients` `Points` object in the final view:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"player"];

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
    self.textKey = @"opponent";

    // Uncomment the following line to specify the key of a PFFile on the PFObject to display in the imageView of the default cell style
    // self.imageKey = @"image";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    //self.paginationEnabled = YES;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    self.objectsPerPage = 50;

    [query includeKey:@"user"];

    PFUser *user = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"user"];

    [query whereKey:user.username equalTo:@"username"];  //where you set the username to the specific user to get only this user's post.
    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.

    if (self.objects.count == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    return query;
}
```

**Thought:**

I guess I might need to take the `PFUser.Username` id from the `Client` object then send it it the `Points View` to display the `Points` object for that specific user in a `PFQueryTableViewController`. If so how would I do so?

**Goal:**

To show the PFUser of the `Clients Object` in the `PointsController` so that I can Show the `Points` object of the PFUser!

Comment: Why do you have two navigation controllers? I don't think the second one is necessary, and it might be causing unexpected behavior in your prepareForSegue.

Comment: Ok say I get rid of it, How do I segue to the Third View with the PFUser data? @doctordoder

Comment: Just push it onto the nav stack. Also, you need to explain your parse data model - are you using relationships? Why not query the relationship contents?

Comment: - In storyboard, control-drag the "Points" button to vc 3 (view controller 3)
- In prepareForSegue of vc 2, give the destination view controller (vc 3) the object it needs (the user's points I guess)
- I don't know why vc 3 has to be a PFQueryTableViewController, it looks like all it needs are the "Points" from the user.

Comment: Because `Points` has a lot of objects. I need to User In VC3 so I can query for the Points related to the user. So how would I write the code for the prepareForSegue? @doctordoder

Comment: @Wain Im Using Relationships. But I need to show the PfUser points in The Third View, but I can't get Their points because No user Is present In that View.

Comment: Get the "Points" in VC2, and then give them to VC3 in the prepareForSegue of VC2->VC3

Comment: So Query Like with - (PFQuery *)queryForTable in VC2? Then how would I pass all of that to VC3? `Points` will have and could have 100 Objects on itself @doctordoder

Comment: @user2977529 You say that from VC1, you have a table of `client`s. Pass that client to VC2, then pass it to VC3, and then in VC3, get the points using `client.points` or whatever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58119/discussion-between-user2977529-and-doctordoder).